# Exporting the entire database for elastic search in csv

Tags: elasticsearch

Any ideas on how to export the entire database in elastic search in csv? I just need one index to be exported.

I tried the following python plugin but elastic search as a service provider is complaining on root certificates:

https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv/blob/master/README.rst

es2csv -i leads -a user:password -u https://host.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243 -q '' -o database.csv

but I get: elasticsearch.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Root certificates are missing for certificate validation. Either pass them in using the ca_certs parameter or install certifi to use it automatically.

help? I'm using Elasticsearch.co as a service for my elastic search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Logstash to export an index to CSV:

```
input {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "some-index"
    query => '{"query": {
                 "match_all": {}
             }}'
}
output {
  file {
    codec => line { format => "%{field1},%{field2}"}
    path => "some-index.csv"
  }
}
```

**Warning**: There is a csv output plugin, but it has a known bug for versions Logstash 5.x. The above configuration should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As taraslayshchuk has already said, es2csv has been updated to support SSL. For an elastic.co hosted ES I've been using something like this:

```
es2csv.py -u https://myserverurl -i myindex-* -r -q '
{
  "query": {
      "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "gte": "2017-04-16T00:00",
                "lt": "2017-04-23T23:59",
                "time_zone": "-06:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
' -o outputfile.csv --auth user:password --use-ssl --verify-certs
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest update of es2csv has a SSL patch, which should resolve your problem.